# if a place is added to google map by using google api than how its scope can be moderated to GOOGLE instead of APP?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Please can anyone answer that how i can able to moderate a APP scope Place added from API to GOOGLE Scope? any details regarding this process will be apreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to migrate places from an `APP` scope to `GOOGLE` scope.  If you would like your places to be eligible for inclusion in Google Maps your best bet is to delete them and re-add them using the `GOOGLE` scope and ensure the `GOOGLE` scope is used for any places added moving forward.

Comment: but how can  add place in google map api using the google scope?